# Moving items up/down in bound collection duplicate items in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections, treeview

When moving objects up and down in a collection which a `TreeView` is bound to, the objects being moved seem to duplicate in the `TreeView` (but not the collection itself that it's bound to). This goes away if I close and reopen the window that contains the `TreeView`.

I'm using a third party .dll which contains their own observable collection class called `GeoCollection` which looks like:

`public class GeoCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`

It contains functions for `MoveUp(string objName)` and `MoveDown(string objName)` which obviously move an item in the collection up or down.

I have a `GeoCollection<Overlay>`, where the `Overlay` class contains a `GeoCollection<Layer>`.

I am binding these to a `TreeView` using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, where the parent nodes will be the `Overlays`, and the children nodes will be `Layers`. I'm filtering these `Overlays` by using an `ICollectionView`.

Below is my `xaml`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding OverlaysViewSource}" Name="LayersTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And here's the related code in my viewmodel:

```
/// <summary>
/// The map's overlays.
/// </summary>
public GeoCollection<Overlay> Overlays { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Filters out the overlays that match the names for user overlays
/// </summary>
public ICollectionView OverlaysViewSource
{
    get
    {
        var itemsToFilter = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Overlays);
        itemsToFilter.Filter = i => (i as Overlay).Name != "useroverlay1" &&
                                    (i as Overlay).Name != "useroverlay2" &&
                                    (i as Overlay).Name != "useroverlay3";

        return itemsToFilter;
    }
}

public LayersViewModel()
{
    Overlays = GetOverlays(); // populates the Overlays collection
}
```

I then try to move objects up and down by calling the `MoveUp` and `MoveDown` functions like so:

`//this gets an overlay by name, goes into it's Layers GeoCollection, and moves the layer object up in the collection`

`Overlays[overlayName]).Layers.MoveUp(layer.Name);`

`//this gets an overlay by name, goes into it's Layers GeoCollection, and moves the layer object down in the collection`

`Overlays[overlayName]).Layers.MoveDown(layer.Name);`

Below is a .gif showing the behavior. The red arrow up button moves the selected layer object up (towards index 0), and the red arrow button down moves the selected layer object down (towards the last index):

[image]

I can confirm the objects are being moved in the collection itself, but the view is not showing it properly unless I refresh the view, navigate away and back to it, etc.

Update1: Here's the code for the MoveDown function that I pulled using .NET Reflector:

```
public void MoveDown(int index)
{
    ValidatorHelper.CheckIEnumerableIsNotNullNorEmpty((IEnumerable) this.mappingCache, "", "");
    ValidatorHelper.CheckInputValueIsInRange((double) index, "index", 0.0, (double) (base.get_Items().Count - 1));
    if ((index > 0) && (index < base.Count))
    {
        T local = base[index];
        base.set_Item(index, base[index - 1]);
        base.set_Item(index - 1, local);
        if (this.mappingCache.ContainsKey(index))
        {
            this.dictionary.set_Item(this.mappingCache[index], base[index - 1]);
        }
        if (this.mappingCache.ContainsKey(index - 1))
        {
            this.dictionary.set_Item(this.mappingCache[index - 1], base[index]);
        }
        string str = this.mappingCache[index];
        this.mappingCache.set_Item(index, this.mappingCache[index - 1]);
        this.mappingCache.set_Item(index - 1, str);
        List<object> list1 = new List<object>();
        list1.Add(local);
        this.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) new PclNotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(PclNotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, (IList) list1, index - 1, index));
    }
}
```

and here's the `OnCollectionChanged`:

```
protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler collectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;
    if (collectionChanged != null)
    {
        collectionChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Update2: I mentioned this above a bit, but navigating away from the `TreeView` and back to it again removes any duplicates/errors and it looks fine.

Update3: The `OnCollectionChanged` event is firing multiple times when moving an item, and I can confirm on the last one the items are in the correct order in the collection.

Comment: Sounds like their INotifyCollectionChanged implementation is broken. Any chance you can just use ObservableCollection? Or try removing and reinserting instead of using their methods: Maybe it's only partly broken.

Comment: I will test it out using an ObservableCollection!

Comment: I might send in a bug report too. If it were my code, I'd want to know. Also check the documentation (if any); maybe they made some very strange decisions and they don't consider whatever it's doing to be "broken". If so you might gain some insights about how to work with what's there.

Comment: Submitted a bug report. Unfortunately they take awhile to respond. However, I have .NET Reflector and updated my post to show their code for the `MoveDown` function and their `OnCollectionChanged`.

Comment: If their `CollectionChanged` wasn't working properly, why would the TreeView show it's items properly when I navigate away from the TreeView and back to it? For instance, the `TreeView` is hosted on a `Tab` in a `TabControl`. When I go to a different tab and come back, the `TreeView` is fine and the items are in the right place.

Comment: I'm guessing it would do that if the items were in a `List<T>`. In a TabControl, if you're populating it via ItemsSource, there's only one actual ContentControl displaying content. When you navigate away and back again, it loads the template XAML all over again, fresh. To put it delicately, that is not how I would have designed TabControl.

Comment: It's a frustration to have all UI state evaporate when you switch tabs and return. However: *are* you populating the tabcontrol via ItemsSource? If you explicitly create TabItems in the XAML, they'll retain their state.

Comment: Yes I am populating it via ItemsSource. Bound to a collection of viewmodels, and then it uses datatemplates to determine the right view to show.

One thing I noticed is that when I put a breakpoint on the MoveUp/MoveDown functions, and then just continue, the TreeView has collapsed. Upon expanding it, the items are in the right order. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The response I got was: Our GeoCollection is not inherited from ObservableCollection, it's inherited from Collection and it contains a Dictionary. Looking over their class, it doesn't actually contain a dictionary, so I have no idea what they are talking about. But removing and reinserting does reflect changes properly, so I'm sticking with that. Thanks again.

Comment: So it's working with their collection, but you have to remove/reinsert? And their explanation is basically that their developers didn't bother doing their jobs? Well, at least you can work around it.